# The problem of zooming in and out beneath the mouse cursor in graphics-view

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I've been studying the graphics-view framework recently and playing around with its basic functionalities.

I've encountered an issue while overloading the scroll wheel event `wheelEvent`. Here's my overridden code:

```
void CView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{
    if (event->modifiers() == Qt::NoModifier) {
        if (event->delta() > 0) {
            zoomIn();
        }
        else {
            zoomOut();
        }
        event->accept();
    }
    else {
        QGraphicsView::wheelEvent(event);
    }
}
```

I've also set the following two properties for `QGraphicsView` based on online suggestions:

```
setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);
setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);
```

However, the problem I'm facing is that when the size of my scene is smaller than the view, the zoom anchor point becomes the center of the view instead of my mouse position. On the other hand, when the scene size is larger than the view, I can zoom at the mouse cursor's position, which doesn't affect the functionality but is very annoying for perfectionists!

For clarification, by "size greater than or less than value," I mean when the width or height of the scene is greater or smaller than the width or height of the view, respectively.

I hope some experienced individuals who have solved this issue before can enlighten me! Your help is greatly appreciated!